# Copy from one instance to another

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine, instance, openstack

I have made two instances in sky-high, called `srv1` and `cl1`. I have connected them together, and can log into `srv1` from `cl1` with the command:

```
Enter-PSSession -Credential $cred' 'IP_OF_SRV1
```

I am now "inside" srv1 from cl1. Now I want to copy items from `cl1` to `srv1`. How do I do this? I tried with the command `robocopy`, but since the path to both the folder I want to copy and the destination folder starts with  `C:\...`, I dont know what to write. How do I separate them?

Comment: It seems you're in the same class as Maria, because you ask the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66171151/9898643). Please read the comments on her question and Google for what a UNC path is.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to search on line, but cant find a way to get my UNC path? I tried the command from this site [link](https://code.adonline.id.au/unc-path-from-local-path-in-powershell/), but I just got an error saying "Sorry, C:/User/Admin is not a networked drive". I dont understand what that means, but I dont want to make a network and do something complicated and big. I just want to copy a folder

Comment: Its just as theo mentioned, you have to specify the UNC path. `\\srv1\c$`

Comment: A UNC path is a naming convention that starts with a double BACKSLASH, then the computer name or its IP address, then another backslash followed by the name of the share and perhaps after that the rest of the path. If the computerName is `cl1`, the share is the C-drive and the rest of the path is `ItIsHere`, you would combine into UNC format as `\\cl1\C$\ItIsHere`. It is really not hard to understand. Just google 'UNC Path'

Comment: I also suggest you read-up on [Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item), and have a look at parameters `-FromSession` and `-ToSession`. There are even examples there on how to use those

Comment: Could someone explain how this question is related to to the `[openstack]` tag?